# Using cluster in NodeJS with websockets

Tags: node.js, websocket

I have a machine that needs to handle a LARGE amount of websocket connections. My research has found that the WebSocket library [(ws)](https://github.com/einaros/ws/) is the best option for handling the load that I am looking to process.

In order to maximize the potential connections I am using the `cluster` lib that is native in NodeJS. When I make 7 child processes and try to connect hundreds of connections, the connection count is heavily waited towards the first process. Does anyone know of a way I can distribute the connections more evenly?

Thanks in advance!

~Mike

Comment: Curious: how large is LARGE?